# How I can create a reference of type std::vector<A>& from std::vector<B> where B is a class inherited from A

Tags: c++, vector, reference, c++17, stdvector

### Project Structure

I have a project structure like this :

```
myProject
├── myLib
│  ├── DataStructures.hpp/cpp
│  └── DeviceManager.hpp/cpp
└── QtDeviceView.hpp/cpp
```

myLib/Datastructures:

```
struct Device {
    std::string name;
    std::string mac;
    Device(std::string &name, std::string &mac) : name(name), mac(mac) {}
    ...
};

struct DeviceA : public Device {
    ...
};

struct DeviceB : public Device {
    ...
};
```

mylibs/DeviceManager:

```
class DeviceManager {
private:
    std::vector<DeviceA> _devicesA;
    std::vector<DeviceB> _devicesB;
    ...
public:
    std::vector<DeviceA> &getDevicesA();
    std::vector<DeviceB> &getDevicesB();
    ...
};
```

QtDeviceView:

```
class MyTableModel : public QAbstractTableModel {
private:
    std::vector<Device> &_my_vector;
public:
    explicit MyTableModel(std::vector<Device> &my_vector);
      
    // QT AbstractTable Implementation (these function use _my_vector)
    int rowCount(const QModelIndex &parent) const override;
    int columnCount(const QModelIndex &parent) const override;
    QVariant headerData(int section, Qt::Orientation orientation, int role = Qt::DisplayRole) const override;
    QVariant data(const QModelIndex &index, int role) const override;
    Qt::ItemFlags flags(const QModelIndex &index) const override;
};
```

---

### Problem encountered

When I want to create a reference in the `QtDeviceView` to one of the vector in `myLib/DeviceManager`, by using a reinterpret cast like this :

```
reinterpret_cast<std::vector<Device>>(this->vc.getDevicesA());
```

I got this compile error:

```
error: invalid cast from type 'std::vector<DeviceA>' to type 'std::vector<Device>'
```

I tried using a pointer cast like this :

```
reinterpret_cast<std::vector<Device>*>(&this->vc.getDevicesA())
```

but it's result in a Segfault.

---

### Question

**How I can create a reference of type `std::vector<A>&` from `std::vector<B>` where B is a class inherited from A ?**

**If such a reference can't be created, what is the best way to implement the QT view class ?**

---

### Notes

I searched multiple solution, but didn't find one that match the following requirement :

- Files in the myLibs/ folder should not include any QT function/class/type
- The _my_vector attribute should be a reference and not a copy to avoid data multiplication/re-creation.

Comment: Short answer: You can't. A reference/pointer to `Device` can be caster to a pointer/reference to `DeviceA`. But casting the whole vector is a different thing, and you shouldn't really need to do that. If you want to pass a range of "anything that is derived from `Device`" you could use ranges or iterators or something similar instead. Then you have abstracted the memory managing part that cares about the actual memory layout of the thing away.

Comment: You can't at least not without making sliced copies. A vector stores it's elements in memory in a layout matching an array layout. If `sizeof(B)` and `sizeof(A)` are different, accessing an element at a given index of a backing storage given vector template params `A` and `B` would yield different memory locations...

Comment: Another approach here is to use a `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Device>>` from the start. Then you could store any device in the vector, including mixing derived classes etc.

Comment: I need to store each kind of device in different vector (in DeviceManager), since it's displayed in different widget and other program use every kind of device very differently. I will look at smart pointer solution, may be shared_prt or weak_ptr could be a solution in this case ?

Comment: You can't do this because it's not safe. Consider `MyTableModel(std::vector<Device> &my_vector) { my_vector[0] = DeviceB(); }` and the effects of `MyTableModel(vc.getDevicesA())`.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot turn a `std::vector<A>` into a `std::vector<B>`, since the backing storage of the vectors store the elements similar to an array. Any attempt to access the backing storage of a vector as if it was a vector with a different template parameter results in undefined behaviour except for very rare circumstances.

The probably simplest solution to this would be to make `MyTableModel` a template with a template parameter matching the one of the `std::vector` you're using.

If this is not an option, you could still wrap the vector in an object responsible for actually retrieving an element or replace the vector reference with `void*` and use a function pointer for an accessor function.

```
class MyTableModel : public QAbstractTableModel {
private:
    void* m_vectorPtr;
    Device& (*m_vectorAccessor)(void*, size_t);

    template<class DeviceType>
    static Device& VectorAccessor(void* vectorPtr, size_t index)
    {
        return (*static_cast<std::vector<DeviceType>*>(vectorPtr))[index];
    }

    Device& GetDevice(size_t index)
    {
        return m_vectorAccessor(m_vectorPtr, index);
    }
public:
    template<class DeviceType>
    explicit MyTableModel(std::vector<DeviceType> &my_vector)
        : m_vectorPtr(&my_vector),
        m_vectorAccessor(&MyTableModel::VectorAccessor<DeviceType>)
    {
    }
      
    ...
};
```

this would allow you to retrieve the vector elements using the `GetDevice` function while not limiting you to a specific device type as vector elements.